# Frama-C slice: parallelizable loop

Tags: frama-c, program-slicing

I am trying to perform a backward slicing of an array element at specific position. I tried two different source codes. The first one is (first.c):

```
const int in_array[5][5]={
                          1,2,3,4,5,
                          6,7,8,9,10,
                          11,12,13,14,15,
                          16,17,18,19,20,
                          21,22,23,24,25
};

int out_array[5][5];
int main(unsigned int x, unsigned int y)
{
  int res;
  int i;
  int j;
  for(i=0; i<5; i++){
    for(j=0; j<5; j++){
      out_array[i][j]=i*j*in_array[i][j];
    }
  }
  res = out_array[x][y];
  return res;
}
```

I run the command:

> frama-c-gui -slevel 10 -val -slice-return main file.c

and get the following generated code:

```
int main(unsigned int x, unsigned int y)
{
  int res;
  int i;
  int j;
  i = 0;
  while (i < 5) {
    j = 0;
    while (j < 5){
      out_array[i][j] = (i * j) * in_array[i][i];
      j ++;
    }
    i ++;
  }
  res = out_array[x][y];
  return res;
}
```

This seems to be ok, since the x and y are not defined, so the "res" can be at any position in the out_array. I tried then with the following code:

```
const int in_array[5][5]={
                          1,2,3,4,5,
                          6,7,8,9,10,
                          11,12,13,14,15,
                          16,17,18,19,20,
                          21,22,23,24,25
};

int out_array[5][5];
int main(void)
{
  int res;
  int i;
  int j;
  for(i=0; i<5; i++){
    for(j=0; j<5; j++){
      out_array[i][j]=i*j*in_array[i][j];
    }
  }
  res = out_array[3][3];
  return res;
}
```

The result given was exactly the same. However, since I am explicitly looking for a specific position inside the array, and the loops are independent (parallelizable), I would expect the output to be something like this:

```
int main(void)
{
  int res;
  int i;
  int j;
  i = 3;
  j = 3;
  out_array[i][j]=(i * j) * in_array[i][j];
  res = out_array[3][3];
}
```

I am not sure if is it clear from the examples. What I want to do is to identify, for a given array position, which statements impact its final result.
Thanks in advance for any support.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You obtain "the statements which impact the final result". The issue is that not all loop iterations are useful, but there is no way for the slicing to remove a statement to the code in its current form. If you perform syntactic loop unrolling, with `-ulevel 5`, then you will each loop iteration is individualized, and slicing can decide for each of them whether it is to be included in the slice or not. In the end, `frama-c-gui -ulevel 5 -slice-return main loop.c` gives you the following code

```
int main(void)
{
  int res;
  int i;
  int j;
  i = 0;
  i ++;
  i ++;
  i ++;
  j = 0;
  j ++;
  j ++;
  j ++;
  out_array[i][j] = (i * j) * in_array[i][j];
  res = out_array[3][3];
  return res;
}
```

which is indeed the minimal set of instructions needed to compute the value of `out_array[3][3]`.

Of course whether `-ulevel n` scales up to very high values of `n` is another question.